# MySQL: How to subtract results of a JOIN from another query?

Tags: mysql, join

I need to exclude the results from a complex query from another query.  I don't know how to make a LEFT JOIN work with the results of another JOIN query.

I want to return fields from `lt`.`contacts` after subtracting (excluding) the result of this:

```
(SELECT `contacts`.`idContacts` AS id, `contacts`.`First_Name`, `contacts`.`Last_Name`
FROM `lt`.`contacts` 
JOIN `lt`.`groups` 
JOIN `lt`.`groups_has_contacts` 
ON Contacts_idContacts=idContacts 
WHERE idGroup 
IN (35) 
AND Groups_idGroup 
IN (35))
```

From the results of this:

```
SELECT * FROM `lt`.`groups_has_contacts` Where `Groups_idGroup` = 37)
```

I'm pulling my hair out -- any help before I am bald would be appreciated!

Comment: I can't even make sense of the first query in your question.  You're doing two joins, but only one of them has an `ON` clause?  So you want the Cartesian product of `contacts` and `groups` to be joined to a third table?

Comment: Your query is unintelligible garbage. Better if you just post the table schemas and state in English what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT contacts.idContacts, contacts.First_Name, contacts.Last_Name
FROM contacts, groups
where contacts.idContacts=groups.idgroup
```

OR

```
SELECT contacts.idContacts, contacts.First_Name, contacts.Last_Name
FROM contacts INNER JOIN groups ON contacts.idContacts=groups.idgroup
```